# How to customize the title link of an object when publishing a open graph action?

Tags: object, facebook-opengraph

I have successful published an action with an object on FB Open Graph. The object includes picture, title (is a link) and description. When I click the title link, it goes to the page from my web server which hosts the data of all the meta tags.

My question is how  I can customize this link to open my facebook app instead of opening the object web page.

I have seen many open graph contents. When I click the object title, it asks me to install the app. I just want to do the same thing.

Just began to do facebook integration. It might be a too easy question, but I really appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Facebook App Dashboard:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps//summary

If your app is iOS, fill out the Native iOS App settings:

- Bundle ID: Your bundle ID
- Facebook Login: Enabled
- Deep Linking: Enabled

For more details, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/link-to-your-native-app-ios-sdk/

If your app is Android, fill out the Native Android App settings:

- Package Name: Your launching activity's package
- Class Name: Your launching activity's class (full class name)
- Facebook Login: Enabled
- Deep Linking: Enabled

For more details, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/link-to-your-native-app/